# How to bind properties of two UI objects in Java?

Tags: java, binding

I have a simple Java application with textfields and buttons. I am looking for the best and quick way to bind the state of one JTextField to the state of one JButton. I'm using Eclipse, so I don't need any tricks of Netbeans IDE.

Suppose a user needs to input a value into a textfield in order to be able to send a request. The button should be enabled only if the value of the textfield is not empty and consists at least of 3 symbols. If the user deletes the input, the button becomes disabled.

I come from the Flex-world. Such a task can be solved there very easy. One should just write something like this:

```
<mx:Button enabled = "{myTextField.text.length >= 3}" />
```

Is there such an opportunity in Java? How is it called? I hope, I don't need to write event listeners for each pair of logicaly connected UI elements, do I?

Comment: Why not write event listeners? That´s how the Observer pattern is implemented in Swing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) on the JTextField. Every time the Document changes, you check the state of your button, like `button.setEnabled(textField.getText().length > 3)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know it is so simple! Could you say me if it is a good practice to process the Document Event in the component where the TextFields are? I mean "myTf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);" Or should I always create a new class to perform the action?

Comment: I don´t really know what the "canon" says on this, I´d probably implement DocumentListener in my class. Inner class is also an option, but I think you can get memory leak problems when using non-static inner classes.

Comment: I see. I changed my JFrame by adding "implements DocumentListener" and  by writing corresponding methods for this interface. So I have at the moment no inner classes. My JFrame is the class, which listens to events from the Document. It works well! Thanks!